# Javascript/jQuery - Use modulus to ensure height of div is a multiple of x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a blog with lots of `div.content`s, each of which I'd like to have a height as a multiple of 22px (so all the text lines up with a background image of a grid). I'm imagining you'd probably do something like:

```
    // loop for each div.content   
    // var height =  $('div.content').height()
    // var modulus = height%22
    // var padding = 22 - modulus
    // $('div.content').css({'padding-left': 'PADDINGpx'})
```

Does that sound about right? I'm not too great with JS. How do you get the padding variable into the jquery function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks fine to me.  You need to use string concatenation to join the variable with the string:

```
$('div.content').css({'padding-left': padding+'px'});
```

One point to make is that if the div *is* a multiple of 22, you'll still be adding 22px to it.  If that's not desired, use an `if` statement to conditionally add the padding:

```
// loop for each div.content   
var height =  $('div.content').height();
var modulus = height%22;
var padding = 22 - modulus;

if (modulus)
    $('div.content').css({'padding-left': padding+ 'px'});
```

ps, don't forget your [semicolon line terminators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399935/why-use-semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('div.content').css({'padding-left': **padding+'px'**})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply just do the following to get the padding in

```
var_padding = 22 - modulus;
$('div.content').css({'padding-left': var_padding})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think giving it a `line-height:22px` should do the trick automatically..

(*maybe i am understanding something wrong, though ..*)

Comment: If there is a picture or a video in a post then all the nicely set up line heights get thrown out.

Comment: @rik, indeed. I did not take into consideration other elements that affect the sizing .. scrap my answer :)