# Does cout need to be terminated with a semicolon?

Tags: c++, cout, comma-operator

I am reading Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming : Principles and Practice Using C++

In the drill section for Chapter 2 it talks about various ways to look at typing errors when compiling the `hello_world` program

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()  //C++ programs start by executing the function main
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n",  // output "Hello, World!"
    keep_window_open();         // wait for a character to be entered
    return 0;
}
```

In particular this section asks:

> Think of at least five more errors you
>   might  have made  typing  in  your
>   program  (e.g. forget
>   `keep_window_open()`, leave  the Caps
>   Lock key on while typing a word, or
>   type a comma instead  of a semicolon)
>   and try each to see what happens when
>   you try to compile and run those
>   versions.

For the `cout` line, you can see that there is a comma instead of a semicolon.
This compiles and runs (for me). Is it making an assumption ( like in the javascript question: [Why use semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399935/why-use-semicolon/2399959#2399959) ) that the statement has been terminated ?

Because when I try for `keep_terminal_open();` the compiler informs me of the semicolon exclusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comma operator in C++ can be used as follows:

```
a, b;
```

It means "do `a`, disregard the result, then do `b`."  You can chain it together like this:

```
a, b, c, (etc.), n;
```

In general, this isn't considered good style.  The comma operator is rarely used in practice because it's confusing.  The few times it's legitimately useful usually come up with for loops:

```
for (int a = 0, b = 0; a < 100; a++, b++) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Here, we use the comma operator in the last part of the for loop to mean "increment both `a` and `b`."

To answer your question, yes, you should have a semicolon after the `cout`.  Using the comma operator technically works as well, but it's inelegant and likely to confuse people.

Comment: Your `for` loop example isn't a use of the comma operator, it's just part of the syntax for variable declaration.

Comment: @Chris Lutz- The first part of the loop is a variable declaration, but the last part (a++, b++) is indeed a use of the comma operator.  I only noticed this after you pointed it out. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef - Right! I should work on my spot-error-and-comment reflex.

Comment: @Chris Lutz- No problem. :-)  You should go with your gut!  Most of the time you'll be right, and the times that you're wrong people are usually forgiving.

Comment: Ok I get it now , I still do not understand why the comma operator cannot be coupled with the return statement though.

Comment: The comma operator can only be used to chain *expressions* together, not *statements*.  return is a statement, not an expression, whereas function calls or printing data with cout are expressions and can be chained together with comma.

Comment: Oh, I am mixing up expressions with statements, now I understand :)

Answer (score 3):

Any statement needs to be terminated by a semi-colon:

```
std::cout << "Hi world";
```

However, among other things, an expression can take the form of `A,B,C`, where `A` and `B` and `C` are evaluated, and then `C` becomes the result.

If you put the following expression:

```
std::cout << "Hi world", 3
```

into a statement:

```
std::cout << "Hi world", 3;
```

then it looks like you did not need the semicolon at the end of the statement. In fact what happened is that you misunderstood what a "statement" really is.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yeah you are right I sat down and looked and tried other combinations of statements with/without semicolons ending a statement preceding return... Could you explain the return ? I thought it was a statement , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k68ktdwf(v=vs.80).aspx or can it not be used with the comma operator ?

Comment: @PhilippeHarewood: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question. `return X;` is indeed a statement; I don't see what that has to do with it though, as your comma was in the preceding statement. Your `return` statement remains unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

it should be terminated with one, yes

Comment: Not necessarily. See my answer.

Comment: so first you knock how i said `should` then used it yourself.

Comment: you said `not necessarily` and then proceeded to say `should` just like i did. SHOULD. not HAVE TO.

Comment: @tekknolagi Where did I say "should"?

Comment: @tekknolagi I think you might have confused me with templatetypedef.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain a few other aspects of the situation...

The comma operator has the lowest precedence of any C++ operators, so - for example - the code...

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << 5, 2;    // outputs 5, complete line/statement evaluates to 2
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << (5, 2);  // outputs 2 (5 is discarded), line evaluates to std::cout
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

...will output "5" at the line commented A, and "2" from B.

Because of this precedence, note that *if* `keep_window_open()` returned `void`, then `std::cout` wouldn't know how to stream it, and you would get a compiler error from...

```
std::cout << keep_window_open(); // can't compile if function return type is void
```

...but still wouldn't be safe in the usage you're exploring...

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n",  // can compile because seen as two comma-separated
keep_window_open();              // subexpressions, so std::cout doesn't try to stream
                                 // a return value from keep_window_open().
```