# Why I get TypeError creating jQuery plugin after modifying String.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, prototype

Try to create a jQuery plugin after you've modified String.prototype, and you get a TypeError. Why? Is it a jQuery's bug? It does bother me when it comes to function ordering. Now I have to always take care of creating jQuery plugins before modifying prototypes. See these fiddles:

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/t6Xdd/) Throws Type Error (because jQuery plugin is created after prototype modification)

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/m6J2D/) is ok.

Comment: Yes, semicolons are important in JS :)

Comment: Semicolons are rarely "important" in JS. They just happen to be in this exact situation where the next line of code is wrapped in (), causing this problem. There aren't many other "important" situations, but it includes the format of return statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a semicolon after this function expressin

```
String.prototype.digitGroup = function () {
    // Code here
    return;
}; // Here
```

[**Updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6Xdd/2/)

Semicolons are optional in `javascript` but some times it matters so you should always use semicolon, it's a  good programming practice, [**check this**](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/semicolons) and also [**this on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399935/why-use-semicolon).

Comment: How strange it was. I never thought of that little little `;` to be the root of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
String.prototype.digitGroup = function () {
    // Code here
    return;
}; // Add a semicolon here to avoid error

(function ($) {
    $.fn.showDialog = function (options) {
        // Code here
        return this;
    };
})($);
```