# Javascript defining object, comma case

Tags: javascript, object

While I was trying some fundemantels in Javascript, I came across a question, which suprised me, and I cannot find an answer to that.
I got the following, which works perfecty:

```
var obj= new Object ();
    obj.test = "Hello" 

    obj.testTwo= function (){
        console.log(this.test)
    },obj.testTwo();
```

When I'm trying it without a comma, it does not work.

```
var obj= new Object ();
    obj.test = "Hello" 

    obj.testTwo= function (){
        console.log(this.test)
    }obj.testTwo();
```

So I tried this as a third option...and it works?

```
var obj= new Object ();
    obj.test = "Hello" 

    obj.testTwo= function (){
        console.log(this.test)
    }
    obj.testTwo();
```

Now I'm quiet confused. Why to use a comma and why does it work with a break?

Comment: [Why Use Semicolons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399935/why-use-semicolon)

Comment: JavaScript fundamental: Use semicolons, even when you think it's optional.

Comment: There are many answers when you search StackOverflow for [javascript comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+comma+operator)

Comment: @jbabey: That's not a JavaScript fundamental. A JavaScript fundamental is ASI, and the developers can decide for themselves if and when to take advantage of it.

Comment: And [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) at MDN.

Comment: just found comma explanations which are not used for anonymous functions, so I asked to make sure I got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

So, it evaluates both your codes. But it doesn't when you put them together.

Read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)...

Example:

It is same as when you do

```
var a = 10, b = 40;
```

Comment: but why just need to use it on an anonymous function and what about the break?

Comment: @ChristophHa Because the line break (sometimes) ends the statement.

Comment: so the break does quiet the same in this case?

Comment: ok seems to be quiet complicated but thanks for you quick reply

Comment: @ATOzTOA To be exact, comma operator in `var` is not a good example here. At the MDN page you've linked, they say: "`Note that the comma in the var statement is not the comma operator..."`. Rather this is one of those rare cases, when ASI can't do the job correctly.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the comma operator in action. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, the comma operator does its duty as it is documentated: "`evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.`" [<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Basicly your second snippet is an assignment. Assignments should always be terminated with a semicolon, even if their last expression would be a block of statements. However, this is not obvious to [ASI](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9). Hence this snippet fails without either a semicolon or a newline between the block and object method call, where interpreter expects to see an operator or a termination of the assignment. If none of these is found, an `Unexpected token` error is thrown. This same explanation stands for why the third snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

Newlines (`\n` or `\r\n`) and commas (`,`) acts as statement separators.